# Using 'Credentials Binding Plugin' in Jenkins, provide password for keystore to use with jarsigner?

Tags: android, jenkins

I have an `Android` project, being packaged into a `.apk`. And now I want to sign the artifact as a step in jenkins with no human intervention. But I dont understand how to supply the actual password?

First, I uploaded `my.keystore` to `Jenkins -> Manage Credentials -> Secret file`.

Then configured my job to:

- `Use secret text(s) or file(s)`
- Set `Variable` to be `mVar`
- Set `Specific credentials` to `my.keystore`

Added an `Execute Shell` to `echo "$myVar"` and the value printed is something like:

```
+ echo /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secretFiles/1f737ec7-c437-4005-8577-5b28edf158e4/my.keystore
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/secretFiles/1f737ec7-c437-4005-8577-5b28edf158e4/my.keystore
```

This is how I manually sign the `.apk` ..

```
osx:~ jenkins$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myProject/workspace/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk myKeystore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Credentials Binding Plugin allows you to bind more than one credential per job.

In the "Use secret text(s) or file(s)" configuration section, you can bind multiple credentials to multiple environment variables.

So under "Bindings" in the job configuration, choose "Add" again and select "Secret text" this time.

There (or via the Credentials page), you can add another credential with the password, and map it to another environment variable.

If your key alias password is different from the keystore password, you can add that as well in the same way.